# Why is stream.pipeline undefined inside extension for vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, node.js-stream

I' trying to use stream.pipeline in my vscode extension, but it is undefined. If i just run another .ts file in the same project via node.js, stream.pipeline is defined and works properly. How do I use stream.pipeline in vscode extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stream.pipeline` was introduced in Node 10.0 while VS Code 1.28 runs extensions in a Node 8.9 environment

Once VS Code [upgrades to Electron 3](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/52629) (which includes node 10.2), you will be able to use this api